# How do I obtain test durations with pytest session_finish?

Tags: python, pytest

Instead of capturing the printed output of `--durations=...`, how can I capture them via e.g. the `pytest_sessionfinish` function?

I've tried to capture them via a dict `self.durations = {}` in a plugin class:

```py
def pytest_runtest_logreport(self, report):
    self.durations[report.head_line] = report.duration
```

But the numbers seem way too low from what pytest itself reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're probably capturing the durations from teardown (or I guess more specifically, you're capturing all of them but the (often trivial) teardown is clobbering the others) -- you need to specifically filter for `.when == 'call'`

```py
class CollectResults:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.times: dict[str, bool] = {}

    def pytest_runtest_logreport(self, report: pytest.TestReport) -> None:
        if report.when == 'call':
            self.results[report.head_line] = report.duration

___

disclaimer: I'm one of the pytest core devs
```